# Selenium - Select an option from a dropdown using a wildcard?

Tags: java, selenium, drop-down-menu, selenium-webdriver

Is it possible to use a wildcard when selecting an option from a dropdown in Selenium? I'm working on a webapp where I upload a file to a server. After uploading the file, I can perform an operation using the file by selecting it from a dropdown. However, the dropdown shows the file as well as the file's size so when looking at the options it will display "File Name - 0.5 GB". I can't use selectByValue, as the value attribute is randomly assigned and I can't use selectByIndex because the order of the options can change depending on how many files are shown.

The best I could come up with would be something like this (Java code):

```
Select sel = = new Select(dropdown);
List<WebElement> list = sel.getOptions();
for (WebElement option : list) {
    if (option.getText().contains(data.getImageName())) {
        sel.selectByVisibleText(option.getAttribute("value"));
        break;
        }
}
```

But I imagine there has to be a better way to select an option from a dropdown when I don't the exact text that will be displayed. Is there?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [`Select` class implementation](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/Select.java), there is only `selectByVisibleText()` related method, but it [relies on the full option text](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/Select.java#109), not a partial one:

```
List<WebElement> options =
    element.findElements(By.xpath(".//option[normalize-space(.) = " + escapeQuotes(text) + "]"));
```

As you can see, it uses an `=` match inside the xpath expression.

The solution would be to find an option "manually" using xpath's `contains()` and call [`setSelected()`](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/Select.java#316):

```
Select sel = = new Select(dropdown);
WebElement option = driver.findElement(By.xpath('//path/to/select//option[contains(., "Partial text")]'));
sel.setSelected(option);
```

Answer (score 0):

Alecxe is right, but unfortunately the `sel.setSelected(option)` method is private. You can find the option element in the page and then select it by id:

```
WebElement option = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//option[contains(.,'" + containValue + "')]"));
Select sel = new Select(element);
sel.selectByIndex(sel.getOptions().indexOf(option));
```

Answer (score -1):

To answer your question it sounds like you're asking for pattern matching. Here's a link to the documentation for Java's [Regular Expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/).

Perhaps you are asking the wrong question.  What are you trying test exactly, ie: how do you know which selection from the drop down you wish to select?